# TypeScript - How can omit some items from an Enum in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I defined an Enum to clarify APIs request status:

```
const enum Errcode{
    Ok=0,
    Error=1,
    AccessDeny=201,
    PostsNotFound=202,
    TagNotFound=203,
    //...
}

type SuccessErrcode =Errcode.Ok;
type NotFoundError =Errcode.PostsNotFound|Errcode.TagNotFound;
type ErrorErrcode=/* there */;
```

How can I define the `ErrorErrcode` that means all items of Errcode except Errcode.Ok (and it should include all items of NotFoundError)?

I can't define the more granular types and [Union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html) them likes this:

```
enum SuccessErrcode {
    Ok =0,
}
enum NotFoundErrcode {
    PostsNotFound=202,
    TagNotFound=203,
}
enum ErrorErrcode {
    Error=1,
}
type Errcode =SuccessErrcode|NotFoundError|SuccessErrcode;
```

If I do this, I will can't use `Errcode.xxx` - for use a code, I must to know where it be assigned of.(e.g. from `Errcode.TagNotFound` to `NotFoundError.TagNotFound`). And consider that - when there have `TagErrcode` and `NotFoundErrcode`, the `TagNotFound=203` will be defined twice.

Answer (score 198, accepted):

As of TypeScript 2.8 and the addition of conditional types, you can use the built-in [`Exclude`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#excludeuniontype-excludedmembers) to exclude certain enum values:

```js
const enum Errcode {
    Ok=0,
    Error=1,
    AccessDeny=201,
    PostsNotFound=202,
    TagNotFound=203,
    //...
}

type SuccessErrcode = Errcode.Ok;
type NotFoundError = Errcode.PostsNotFound|Errcode.TagNotFound;
type ErrorErrcode = Exclude<Errcode, Errcode.Ok>;
```

[Typescript Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=const%20enum%20Errcode%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Ok%3D0%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Error%3D1%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20AccessDeny%3D201%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20PostsNotFound%3D202%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20TagNotFound%3D203%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F...%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20SuccessErrcode%20%3D%20Errcode.Ok%3B%0D%0Atype%20NotFoundError%20%3D%20Errcode.PostsNotFound%7CErrcode.TagNotFound%3B%0D%0Atype%20ErrorErrcode%20%3D%20Exclude%3CErrcode%2C%20Errcode.Ok%3E%3B)

Comment: For some reason the `ErrorErrcode` in my local Typescript configuration results in type `Errcode`. Both this example and my specific problem work in the Typescript playground though. I don't know what could cause this.

Comment: Is there some way that resulting value is also enum instead of type?

Comment: Typescript didn't have the Exclude type when I submit this question. Good v2.8

Answer (score 11):

You would first define the more granular types. Perhaps something like this:

```
enum ErrorCode {
    Error = 1,
    AccessDeny = 201,
    PostsNotFound = 202,
    TagNotFound = 203,
}

enum SuccessCode {
    Ok = 0
}
```

You can then define a [Union Type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html) to be either a `SuccessCode` or a `ErrorCode`:

```
type ResultCode = ErrorCode | SuccessCode;
```

which you can then use like this:

```
const myResult1: ResultCode = ErrorCode.AccessDeny;
const myResult2: ResultCode = SuccessCode.Ok;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. but there have 2 problems: 1. can't use `Errcode.OK` and `Errcode.Error` no longer, must be `SuccessCode.OK` and `ErrorCode.Error`, 2. If I want to sort the Error Code, e.g. `NotFoundError` and `TagError`, they have a common item `TagNotFound`, how can do in this?

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure you can get a solution for (1.) easily (if at all) - at least not if you want to stay D.R.Y.. Every one has their own opinion but the way I have described it above feels quite natural (every error code is a result code but a success code is not an error code, etc.). I am afraid I just don't follow what you mean for point (2.) but perhaps it would be best asked as a new question?

Comment: I have supplemented the question. no offense. this question discuss "omit-some items from an enum" at start. It circumvents the problem that define the more granular types, and with some side effects.

Answer (score 3):

This took quite a bit of time to figure out. There really has not been an answer to this question in all its incarnations that worked for me. I needed to be able to treat the new value set the same way as the original enum, i.e. populate selection lists with it etc.

Then I was stuck for a bit on the fact that `Object.entries()` produces an array of arrays from a dictionary, and I had to convert this back into a dictionary so that my existing code continued to work with either type.

`reduce()` to the rescue!

Here is my solution (credit goes to Jake Holzinger's answer [to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55464705/simple-way-to-create-javascript-dictionary-from-array-of-arrays)):

```
enum Countries {
  UnitedStates = 'United States',
  Afghanistan = 'Afghanistan',
  Albania = 'Albania'}

const UsAndIslands = [
  Countries.UnitedStates];

const NonUsCountries = Object.entries(Countries)
  .filter((country) => !UsAndIslands.includes(country[1]))
  .reduce((dict, [key, value]) => Object.assign(dict, { [key]: value }), {});

console.log("Countries", Countries);
console.log("NonUsCountries", NonUsCountries);
```

[Try it out.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAwg9mEAXATgS2AZygbwFBRQCqIaSwAJgMpICG52AvFAOQlmVQ31YsA0BKAEEAZgHMAFrVKY6IKMxajJ0tLOn9BQgDYAjVbQWsd%200rRYBfPHgDGcELOKYhICgElM26RSZQA2oLwiKgYmAB07OTUdAwAugDc1nYOSFAAcvZEmEHI6FhGAPK6AFbANkhhoCFYABQ51ZgAlIJhImja5Cg1NXbBKACejQoAfFAAhFku7p7e4WggNtpgFLW9uf1%20AIyxjc2EYSiUYDbA3RRo5Xz%20ANbA-VcAbrRLwDsjUEWl5WG0mJhoYhANXOl1wNzusQAXFAni8oBZGlccAjErZ7Jg4NpgGFtHAxDUAET1PKYAlXYmhRqJZIYrE4vGEjIgLIUrBk9KZbIIXKU%20JAA)

Answer (score 0):

If you want the "typed" version of the above (plus some refinements):

```
enum Country {
  Afghanistan = 'Afghanistan',
  Albania = 'Albania',
  Guam = 'Guam',
  UnitedStates = 'United States'
}

const usAndIslands: Country[] = [Country.Guam, Country.UnitedStates];

const nonUsCountries: { [x: string]: string | Country } = Object.entries(Country)
  .filter((country: [string, string | number]): boolean =>
    typeof country[1] === 'number' && !usAndIslands.includes(country[1]))
  .reduce((dict: {}, [key, value]: [string, string | Country): { [x: string]: string | Country } =>
    Object.assign(dict, { [key]: value }), {});

console.log(nonUsCountries);
```

And if you want the result to be a `Country[]`, you would use this:

```
const nonUsCountries: Country[] = Object.entries(Country)
  .filter((country: [string, string | number]): boolean =>
    typeof country[1] === 'number' && !usAndIslands.includes(country[1]))
  .map(([, value]: [string, string | Country): Country => val as Country);
```

And here is an abstracted function you can use with any numeric enum:

```
/**
 * Returns an array of enum values given an enum and disallowed values.
 *
 * @param myEnum The enum name.
 * @param disallowedValues An array of values of myEnum that should not be returned.
 *
 * @return An array of all myEnum values without the disallowedValues.
 */
export const numericEnumFilterOut: Function =
  <R extends number, T extends {[key: string]: R}>(myEnum: T, disallowedValues: R[]): R[] =>
    Object.entries(myEnum)
      .filter((type: [string, string | R]): boolean =>
        typeof type[1] === 'number' && !disallowedValues.includes(type[1]))
      .map((type: [string, R]): [string, R] => type as [string, R])
      .map(([, value]: [string, R]): R => value);
```

Usage:

```
const nonUsCountries: Country[] =
  numericEnumFilterOut(Country, [Country.Guam, Country.UnitedStates]);

console.log(nonUseCountries);
```