# Simple way to create JavaScript dictionary from Array of Arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary

I have a list of lists, each inner list has 2 items. I want to transform it into a dictionary.

```
const have = [['a', 1], ['b', 2]]
const want = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
```

In python I would do

```
>>> dict([['a', 1], ['b', 2]])
{'a': 1, 'b': 2}
```

What is the easiest way (1-liner) to achieve this in JavaScript?

The easiest way I can think of is a 2-liner.

```
const have = [['a', 1], ['b', 2]]
const want = {}
have.forEach(([key, value]) => want[key] = value)
```

Comment: `new Map([iterable])` is what you are looking for here. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map

Comment: Close enough, but I cannot `JSON.stringify()` that. Is there an easy way to turn it into a dict?

Comment: Thats fair, added an example using `Array.prototype.reduce` as well. That will work for you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the future it'll be:

```
 const want = Object.fromEntries(have);
```

It will hopefully be part of ES2019, and is already supported in some browsers. [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries)

Until the support gets better, your two-liner is the way to go.

Comment: sadly there's no "official" polyfill on MDN

Comment: That is what I was looking for. I'd just make a polyfill using this API and wait for browser adoption. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If you really must have this as a one-liner you could use reduce.

```
const have = [['a', 1], ['b', 2]];
const want = have.reduce((dict, [key, value]) => Object.assign(dict, {[key]: value}), {});
```

It's not very readable though and it creates a throwaway object for each element. I generally prefer readability over trying to get clever with one-liners.

Comment: or simply `Object.assign(...have.map(([k,v]) => ({[k]: v})))`, but this is horrible too.

Answer (score 1):

Examples of using Map and Reduce.

I think because of you `JSON.stringify()` you will be wanting `Reduce`

```js
// using Map
const have = [
  ['a', 1],
  ['b', 2]
];
let want = new Map(have);

console.log(want.get('a'));

// Using Reduce
want = have.reduce((a, v) => {
  a[v[0]] = v[1];
  return a;
}, {});

console.log(want);

console.log(JSON.stringify(want));
```