# Remove entry from enum typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, enums

I have an enum

```
export enum FloorTypeEnum {
  ENGINEERED_HARDWOOD = 'engineered_hardwood',
  SOLID_HARDWOOD = 'solid_hardwood',
  LAMINATE = 'laminate',
  LVT_VINYL = 'vinyl',
  CARPET = 'carpet',
  RUG = 'rug',
  CERAMIC = 'ceramic',
  CONCRETE = 'concrete',
  EPOXY = 'epoxy',
  FLOOR = 'floor', // deprecated value for backward compatibility
}
```

So at one place, I want to use this enum but remove the deprecated value (`Floor`).
Is there any way we can do?

I have tried below

```
export type NewFloorTypeEnum = { 
    [key in Exclude<FloorTypeEnum , FloorTypeEnum .Floor> ]?: string
 };
```

I'm also maintaining an legacy enum

```
export enum LegacyFloorTypeEnum {
 FLOOR = 'floor'
}
```

But I'm confused on how to use that type. I want to use the key and value of the enum and return to frontend.
Ultimate requirement is to get an enum which is equivalent to `FloorTypeEnum - LegacyFloorTypeEnum`. I don't want to create a new enum for new floor values.

Thanks

Comment: Normally this is what you version your libraries/APIs for so you can switch to the next version in which  you removed this value entirely. In lieu of that, rather than trying to remove it, you probably want to maintain a list of "values to ignore" until you're ready for a proper major update in which all deprecated fields are removed.

Comment: yeah. I'm in transition to move to a major update, but not there yet. I'm keeping another enum like 
```
enum LegacyFloorType {
 FLOOR = 'floor'
}
```
so how do i exclude this?

Comment: What version of typescript are you running?

Comment: @Dom I'm using 3.6.4

Comment: Could [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52953852/7644018) possibly help?

Comment: @Paul T. , But the problem is, it gives me type, not the enum, and when I use that, it gives me error"is defined as type and used as value"

Comment: Is the goal to omit any props from legacy?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly, would something like this suffice?

```
export enum FloorTypeEnum {
  ENGINEERED_HARDWOOD = 'engineered_hardwood',
  SOLID_HARDWOOD = 'solid_hardwood',
  LAMINATE = 'laminate',
  LVT_VINYL = 'vinyl',
  CARPET = 'carpet',
  RUG = 'rug',
  CERAMIC = 'ceramic',
  CONCRETE = 'concrete',
  EPOXY = 'epoxy',
  FLOOR = 'floor', // deprecated value for backward compatibility
}

enum LegacyFloorTypeEnum {
  FLOOR = 'floor',
  NOT_FLOOR = 'not_floor'
 }

type NewFloorTypeEnum<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K];
}

// test case
const ok: NewFloorTypeEnum<FloorTypeEnum> = LegacyFloorTypeEnum.NOT_FLOOR;
```

I do not believe that Typescript can block FLOOR since they both share the same key/value (I may be wrong in this assumption so please take with a grain of salt). However, if you were to have a new value, in this is example I used `NOT_FLOOR`, it will throw an error if you try using a value in the enum that doesn't match the `FloorTypeEnum`.

Let me know if this does not meet your needs. Happy coding.